# nginx : How to make nginx point to django

Tags: django, nginx

Iam new to nginx.

I have configured nginx,gunicorn and django.

when i start nginx, it gives an error as,
404 Not Found
nginx/1.1.19

as it is not pointing to django.

Now i need to point out nginx to django(using gunicorn as middleware) in conf file using location or root.

Can anyone tell me how to point out nginx to django.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've got many Apps running like this:

```
server {
    # listen, statics, media, etc

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; # Gunicorn Server
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to actually have the gunicorn process running. Do this either manually, or ideally using a process management tool such as [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Here's a sample supervisord script that runs a gunicorn process on a django project:

```
[program:example]
user=ubuntu
group=ubuntu
directory=/home/ubuntu/dev/example
command=python manage.py run_gunicorn -c gunicorn_config.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=True
```

Then you need a proper nginx conf. Here's a minimal sample based off a site running in production:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    # use this if you're serving static assets locally
    location /static/ {  # make sure this is your STATIC_ROOT
        alias /home/ubuntu/dev/example/static/;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to point nginx to django using location or root. Please suggest me in this.

Comment: Don't you have to set up gunicorn to run on port 8080 with the nginx configuration you have here?